# Python- How sort matrix

Tags: python

I have a big matrix import for one .csv more than 50.000 lines.

I am working with panda and numpy, the matrix is a film data base, I would like to sort the matrix by budget and see for example 10 first line showing all columns for this matrix.

Example: Sort by revenue, this is my objective.

```
IMDb_data[['film', 'budget', 'revenue','vote_average','cast']].head(3)

film    budget  revenue   vote_average ..... cast   director    homepage
J.Park  100000    150          5       .....  AAA      BBB      CCC.com
Sun     50000     75           4       .....  AAA      BBB      CCC.com
Night    2000     50           3       .....  AAA      BBB      CCC.com
```

Code use for import the IMDb_data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
IMDb_data= pd.read_csv('tmdb-movies.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IMDb_data.sort_values(by=['budget'], ascending=False)` to sort by budget.

`IMDb_data.sort_values(by=['revenue'], ascending=False)` to sort by revenue.

[pandas.DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `sort_values` method, you can precise by which column, and the order (ascending or descending)

```
df.sort_values(by='budget', ascending=False)
```

For more keywords, you can check out the official [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

`by` is taking either a string (to sort with one column) or a list of string to sort by lexicographic order

`ascending` is taking a boolean (default True)